# What is Hidden Flows and MegaFlow in OVS?

Tags: openflow

Can someone explain, what is Hidden flows and MegaFlow with examples.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hidden flows in OVS are used by the controller to talk to the switch, you typically won't want these to show up in Netflow hence they are hidden by default. If you use the command; 'ovs-ofctl dump-flows br' you will get all flows except the hidden ones, if you use the command; 'ovs-appctl bridge/dump-flows br' you'll also get the hidden ones.

Megaflows are a totally different concept and were introduced in OVS 1.11 and are meant to increase performance by being able to match on arbitrary wildcards to populate the cache and thus use the fast-path for forwarding. Before OVS 1.11 flows were only matched on the exact header, so if lot's of traffic came from the same source with different header info (i.e. a port scan for example) it would all be slow-path actions since none matched the cache entries.

For full details on matching flows, including megaflows, see http://conferences.sigcomm.org/sigcomm/2014/doc/slides/211.pdf

Or listen to packet pushers show 219 which explains it well;
http://packetpushers.net/podcast/podcasts/show-219-open-vswitch-obtains-ludicrous-speed/